# Set of navigation actions in Material Design

Tags: navigation, mobile-application, material-design

I am an android developer. There is a screen of Completed level in my application. There are several options that user can choose:

- go to the next level or next chapter (if it was final level)
- repeat this level for another character
- view replay of this level

What can I use to describe this interface? 3 buttons under each other? Bottom sheet? List of options (as on screenshot).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, so depending on your specific scenario you'lll probably need one of these:

[**Bottom App Bar**](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html)

> ## When to use
>
> **Bottom app bars should be used for:**
>
> - Mobile devices only
> - Access to a bottom navigation drawer
> - Screens with two to five actions

otherwise, if these actions are main areas (I don't think so, but just in case), you'll probably need

**[Bottom Navigation](https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html#)**

## When to use

> **Bottom navigation should be used for:**
>
> - Top-level destinations that need to be accessible from anywhere in the app
> - Three to five destinations
> - Mobile or tablet only

Comment: I think that theese options are suitable only for top-level navigation items. But in my case I have 3 navigation action, that actual only on this screen.

Comment: then bottom bar app, it's used for on screen actions